# How to create a key from a range?

Tags: python

I have to create a dictionary which counts the frequency of the range of numbers in the parameter list, the trick is it has to have three keys: The dictionary is to have three keys: 0, 1, and 2.  A key of 0 represents numbers from 0 - 9, a key of 1 represents numbers from 10 - 19 and a key of 2 represents numbers from 20 - 29. This is what I have so far:

```
def create_numbers_dictionary(numbers):
    a_dict = {}
    for num in numbers:
        if num in range(0, 10):
            key = 0
        elif num in range(10, 21):
            key = 1
        else:
            key = 2
    for num in numbers:
        if num not in a_dict:
            a_dict[key] = 1
        else:
            a_dict[key] += 1
    return a_dict
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: (I can certainly see one: in your first loop, key is continuously reset, and will only contain the value corresponding to the last number when entering the second loop. You'll want to merge the loops.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an interesting description of a task for the code, but please keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*. Please read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question**, ideally starting with a question word like "why" or "how", and ending with a question mark (`?`). Your question should relate to the *specific* difficulty you are having. It also helps to show some example inputs and the expected output, so we can be sure about the description of the problem. Right now, I am not clear what you mean about keys in the dictionary "representing" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't need to be complicated.

```
import collections

a_dict = collections.Counter()
for num in numbers:
    a_dict[num//10] += 1
print(a_dict)
```

Or even a simple list:

```
a_dict = [0,0,0]
for num in numbers:
    a_dict[num//10] += 1
print(a_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your attempt:

1. The first loop finished before starting the second loop, so you only have one value of `key` to work with in the second loop. Instead, all should happen in one loop. Remove the second line that has `for num in numbers:`.
2. You should not check whether a `num` occurs in `a_dict`, as you don't key by `num`, but by `key`. So it should be `if key not in a_dict:`

With those two fixes it will work.

With `Counter` and list comprehension, it could become:

```
from collections import Counter
a_dict = Counter([num // 10 for num in numbers])
```

If `a_dict` must be a plain dict, and not a subclassed one, then add:

```
a_dict = dict(a_dict)
```

Comment: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a dict subclass, I don't think you need the explicit dict conversion.

Comment: @ljmc, I just added that `dict()` call so it doesn't print differently. It depends on how the solution is tested for correctness. But I updated my answer to make that a separate remark.